# Selenium python (webdrivers): how to handle cases with multiple interconnected windows

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking for a way to track an app built on multiple interconnected windows.

Basically I have webdriver running happily, and launch the application which open a window; I can access its elements and everything is fine.

But there is another part of the application, that open on its own, which cause the main view to close. It is still the same application, but the main window is destroyed and the new one is created.

This cause sadly the issue that webdriver can't find the context anymore (because rightfully so, the app to which it was attached, has been destroyed).

content shell came up empty, the driver is Chromedriver 2.23.40 on OSX

Is there a way to handle such case with Selenium python webdriver?

Comment: Have you tried using `driver.switch_to.window(<window handle>)`? If not, you can get the list of window handles using `driver.window_handles`. Typically the window at index 0 is the default window handle, and new window handles are appended, in order.

Comment: Right you are; I was not aware that there was a way to get all the windows and to switch to another window. This solve my problem, Thanks! Feel free to set it as answer, so I can mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium has a `switch_to` method to control switching the active window.

```
# Get window handles
windows = driver.window_handles
print("Number of window handles: {0}".format(len(windows))
print("Current window handle: {0}".format(driver.current_window_handle)

# Switch that most recently opened one
driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1])
print("New window handle: {0}".format(driver.current_window_handle)
```